# jQuery getJSON content in new div

Tags: jquery, html, json

Could some one help me. How to load my data in new divs
[Iv got this one. All is going into one div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSGr6.png)

[And how to make right that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exme0.jpg)

Im just asking how to make : Divs should create automatically depending on json file ( amount of data)

my json:

```
[
{
"name":"wat1",
"number":"42306810738002982912",
"city":"mat1",
"amount":"50 000,00",
"currency":"qwe1",
"rate":"7,40%"
},
{
"name":"wat2",
"number":"42306840338002521455",
"city":"mat2",
"amount":"153,85",
"currency":"qwe2",
"rate":"2,85%"
 },
 {
"name":"wat3",
"number":"42307752138002500019",
"city":"mat3",
"amount":"1500,00",
"currency":"qwe3",
"rate":"0,01%"
 }
]
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("accounts.json", function(data){
$.each(data, function(key, value){
$("name").append(value.name)
$("number").append(value.number)
$("city").append(value.city)
$("amount").appoend(value.amount)
$("currency").append(value.currency)
$("rate").append(value.rate);
});
});
});
```

and html:

```
        <div class="deposit-small-block first-block size-small-block tt" onclick="view('t1'); return false">
            <div class="button_block">
                <div class="div-for-button">
                    <input type="radio" name="on">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="deposit-form-block-name">
                <div class="deposit-form-block-name-first white-text"><name></name></div>
                <div class="deposit-form-block-name-second white-text"><number></number></div>
                <div class="deposit-form-block-name-third white-text"><city></city></div>
            </div>
            <div class="deposit-form-block-sum">
                <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text">
                    <amount></amount><br><currency></currency>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="deposit-form-block-perc">
                <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text"><rate></rate></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/*

var data = [
{
"name":"wat1",
"number":"42306810738002982912",
"city":"mat1",
"amount":"50 000,00",
"currency":"qwe1",
"rate":"7,40%"
},
{
"name":"wat2",
"number":"42306840338002521455",
"city":"mat2",
"amount":"153,85",
"currency":"qwe2",
"rate":"2,85%"
 },
 {
"name":"wat3",
"number":"42307752138002500019",
"city":"mat3",
"amount":"1500,00",
"currency":"qwe3",
"rate":"0,01%"
 }
];


*/
function buildRow(a,b,c,d,e,f){
return '<div class="deposit-small-block first-block size-small-block tt" onclick="view(\'t1\'); return false">\
            <div class="button_block">\
                <div class="div-for-button">\
                    <input type="radio" name="on">\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="deposit-form-block-name">\
                <div class="deposit-form-block-name-first white-text"><name>'+a+'</name></div>\
                <div class="deposit-form-block-name-second white-text"><number>'+b+'</number></div>\
                <div class="deposit-form-block-name-third white-text"><city>'+c+'</city></div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="deposit-form-block-sum">\
                <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text">\
                    <amount>'+d+'</amount><br><currency>'+e+'</currency>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="deposit-form-block-perc">\
                <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text"><rate>'+f+'</rate></div>\
            </div>\
        </div>'
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("accounts.json", function(data){
data = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(data, function(key, value){
$("#main_list").append(
buildRow(value.name
,value.number
,value.city,value.amount,value.currency,value.rate)
);
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main_list'>

</div>
```

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ov-TJi--Z8OEVvZWdPR0hoMTA/view?usp=sharing) something wrong or im just can't see the misstake

Comment: could u just check where i did a misstake. it is just can't load div and data

Comment: Code updated, we need to use `JSON.parse(data)` and now should work

Comment: Still the same. There is no error in debugger, but it can't load the data from function. There is no bars and text. Can't find where is the misstake.

Comment: I have a question always asked in this case.

Comment: Do you run your code over `file:///`or `http(s)://` ?

Comment: via localhost
jquery and getJSON worked for me, data from json file loaded, i attached a screenshot, when i created a question. so i think the problem is no in "Run".

Comment: I sent you a link with files(json,css,html), Is it working on your pc?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ov-TJi--Z8Q1BwbkFsbVdveFU/view?usp=sharing) - it is a new link with updated JSON.parse

Comment: your json file is not valid

Comment: when i add var `data = [{},{}];` ,  i did to test without ajax

Comment: so where is the problem? or im just blind and can't see the right way?)

Comment: 1. Open accounts.json and remove `var data = ` and last `;`
2. Open index.html and remove `data = JSON.parse(data)`
3. Now it works you need to customize your style.css as you like

Comment: yes, you are right, it is working now, thank you very much for your help

Comment: glad to help you :)